# Django South migration and self related model with proxy models

Tags: python, django, model, django-south, relation

I have a model called Person and I added a field called friend which is a relation to itself:

```
class Person(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_lenght=300)
      friend = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

and I have another proxy model that inherit from Person:

```
class Actor(Person):
  ...
  class Meta:
      proxy = True
```

I wanted to make a migration using South, so I did:

```
~$ ./manage.py schemamigration --auto person
~$ ./manage.py migrate person
```

but I got an error in the migration file:

```
,
^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

which corresponds to this piece of code:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

def forwards(self, orm):
    db.create_table(u'persons_person', (
        ,
    ))
```

does anyone knows how to fix this problem? I think the problem is the self related field and the proxy model has nothing to do with this, but I put it as well, just in case.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Re-test this using the south development version and if there's still a  problem open a bug and attach the related models and migrations file.

Comment: Also you can try to comment out the that piece of code in the migration file and it may as well work..